# spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout not working for PostgreSQL

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like to have an option to limit all Spring jpa queries to a certain time limit. If a query takes longer than the specified limit it should be cancelled. From what I saw this can be achieved by using `javax.persistence.query.timeout` and since I am in a Spring context:

```
spring: 
  jpa:
    properties:
      javax.persistence.query.timeout: 10000
```

This should limit all queries executed from spring repositories to 30 seconds, but it's not working. This repository method takes 20 seconds:

```
@Query(value = "select count(*) from pg_sleep(20)", nativeQuery = true)
int slowQuery();
```

I tried it with Postgresql 9.6.11 and with Postgresql 10.5.

Is there some problem with these Postgres versions? Is there any other way to achieve the query execution timeout?

Comment: Generally speaking it is a query hint, if it works when defined globally kind of depends on the hibernate version you are using. It should work for Hibernate 5.4.6 and up.

Comment: My hibernate version is: `5.4.10.Final`

Comment: The relevant bug is: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13493 Double check if you have 5.4.10.

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to find slow queries consider using `AvailableSettings.LOG_SLOW_QUERY`:  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.html#LOG_SLOW_QUERY

Comment: @RobertNiestroj I confirm that I have the version `5.4.10.Final`

Comment: @RobertNiestroj I just verified by debugging that in `SessionImpl` in `applyQuerySettingsAndHints()` the parameter is passed correctly.

Comment: @NoahMartin Did the below answer work for you?

Comment: @NoahMartin How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The following code should be a good alternative.

YAML file:

```
spring:
    jpa:
        properties:
            javax:
                persistence:
                    query:
                        timeout: 10000
```

Comment: can confirm that for a SpringBoot project you'd add the following line to your application.properties: spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout=10000. Take note that the timeout is defined in millis. Should be applicable to most DB's.